# Xmas Special: 25 identical sweets shared between two indivuduals and....

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, permutations, order-statistics

Ready?..

25 identical sweets must be shared bewteen 1 boy & 1 girl.
Each of the children MUST recieve at least 10 sweets each.
all sweets must be distrubuted.
order not important although  I will say this...

I am only looking the total number of unique arrangments, e,g..

1 2 3 4 5

2 4 5 3 1

3 5 3 2 4

the above are displaying exactly the same imformation but in different order such combinations are NOT permited here.

Excuse my lack of mathematical terminologies, (still learning) and merry xmas to you all!

Seasoning Greetings!

Comment: $X+Y = 25$ and  $X, Y\geq 10$?

Comment: When you say the sweets are identical, that implies that only the number of sweets each child gets is important (since we can't distinguish between two sweets).  Is that the interpretation you intended, or are the sweets somehow distinguishable (e.g., labeled $1, 2,\ldots, 24,  25$)?

Comment: the sweets are indeed distinguishable as well as the two individuals

Comment: If you don't tell either of those two people that there *are* sweets, you can keep them all yourself. (So my answer is going to be that there's only one reasonable way to do this)

Comment: i dont understand please explain

Comment: @JosephP Meelo is jokingly giving you the solution of keeping all the sweets for yourself.

Comment: lol, everybody is comedian. thanks straints

Answer (score 1):

So if these 'identical' sweets are in fact distinguishable, there are this many ways:

$${25 \choose 10} +  {25 \choose 11} + {25 \choose 12} + {25 \choose 13} + {25 \choose 14} + {25 \choose 15}$$

---

*Added:* To try and cut through the conversation in the thread below, let me say this is the number of ways that 25 objects can divided up into two sets, one labelled $B$ for boy, the other labelled $G$ for girl, such that each set has at least 10 members. The calculation here by its construction does not allow for ordering of elements of $B$ and $G$; for example, these two partitions are counted **once**, not twice:

$$1: B = \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}, G = \{ 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 \}$$
$$2: B = \{ 10, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5\}, G = \{ 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 \}$$

Comment: so how many combinations would that be? bearing in my my constraints that from my initial question

Comment: @JosephP It's $25852920$ many combinations (used Mathematica)

Comment: Lots. I'll let you do the calculation. But this assuming that receiving 1,2,3,4,5 is the same as receiving 2,1,5,4,3. Is that your intent or not?

Comment: indeed simon that is my intent

Comment: Then this is the answer.

Comment: how do i remove this duplicates so to speak?

Comment: That's what the expression ${n \choose k}$ does. It says pick $k$ objects out of an original set of $n$, and we are indifferent to the order in which they are picked. You might find it helpful to look up combinations, e.g., at Khan Academy.

Comment: theres over 25 million combinations but I believe the majority of these are reangments of previous combinations as mentioned in my earlier post

Comment: I'll point out that the first three and last three terms are equal, basically representing the fact that swapping the roles of the girl and the boy doesn't change the problem.

Comment: @JosephP, not so. Stants, exactly.

Comment: please elaborate

Comment: For example ${25 \choose 10}$ tells us exactly the number of ways I can divide the set of $25$ distinct objects into two sets, one with $10$ objects, the other with $15$. A set by its nature doesn't come with an ordering, so the 'duplicates' you are talking about are removed.

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/prob_comb/combinations

Comment: So simon are you saying that thi 25 million combination s are all authentic so to speak are do you too believe that the majority would be callsed as 'duplicates' and not what im after?

Comment: The 25,852,920 are distinct up to orderings and contains no duplicates in the sense you are using the word.

Comment: my wording might be slighty off but do you get the gist of what im trying to convey?

Comment: also i looked at the site you reccomended but there is no one to seek adive from ineed someone who is able to cut short the unessary 'orders'

Comment: See added text in my answer above. I hope this answers your query.

Comment: i see no added text